# Will html5 geolocation.watchposition work, if user is not on the page?

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I want to create mobile-first web-app, that will track geolocation of busses. Drivers will open site and click "track me" button. Page will use geolocation.watchposition. so I wonder, if driver will shut down display, or watch another pages in the internet, 
Will  geolocation.watchposition work and send geolocation in db?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if the user gives the mobile phone GPS access permission the app will track the device as long as the app is open or in the background (minimized).

Answer (score 0):

No it will NOT work!

See complete example at https://github.com/RichardMaher/Brotkrumen

For the complete story of why PWAs continue to be denied this essential functionality see: -
https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/745